# Помогите пожалуйста выполнить дом задание

Tags: c, массивы, динамические-массивы

Написать программу на C.

A,Б Я сделала , В не могу.....[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 2):

```
int aSize = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);  
for (int i = 0; i < aSize; i++)
{
    if (a[i] > 0)
        a[i] = i * i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (a[i] > 0)
  a[i] = i * i;
```